# Copied value disappears when row that contained source value is deleted in Google spreadsheets

Tags: triggers, google-sheets, range, delete-row

I wrote this script that is used as a trigger onEdit in a sheet. The idea is to pick a value from a worksheet, copy it into another worksheet based on some logic, and then delete the source row that contained the original value.

When run, often times, the copy will take place, but on delete, the copied value will disappear. One way I noticed fixes the problem is if I delete the trigger, save, and create it again...

How can I avoid this behavior?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var entry = range.getSheet();
  var sss = entry.getParent();

  if (sss.getName() != "Weight Tracker")
     return;

  if (entry.getName() != "Entry")
     return;

  Logger.log("CopyData is running...."+range.getCell(1,2).getValue());

  var weight = range.getCell(1,2).getValue();
  Logger.log("weight = "+weight);

  var details = sss.getSheetByName('Details'); 
  var trange = details.getRange(3, 1, 200);
  var data = trange.getValues();

  var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);

  for(var n=0;n<data.length;n++) {
    var date = new Date(data[n]).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    Logger.log("date = "+date+" =? "+today);

    if(date == today) {
        break
    };
  }

  Logger.log("n = "+n+" today: "+today);

  // n is 0 based, sheet is 1 based + 2 headers = 3, 5 is Jim's weight
  details.getRange(n+3,5).setValue(weight);
  // get rid of the row so next addition arrives to the top row
  Logger.log("deleting row...");
  // for some reason deleting the road removes the value entered...
  range.getSheet().deleteRow(1);
}
```